# momentum and energy of the rods

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-mechanics, energy, energy-conservation, conservation-laws

[image]

I have two electromagnets and I attach them to two rods(same mass) such that, first one will be attached to centre of first rod and the second one will be to the end of second rod. Now I bring them close and switch the current on. When this happens, because of the magnetic force, the both rods will repel and move away(arranged such that).

Now what is the energy and what is the momentum in both the rods, considering no losses.

The second rod will have both angular momentum and linear momentum and first rod will have only linear momentum. How to explain conservation of momentum in this case.

In the image green rectangles represents the electromagnets and black rectangles represent the rods

Comment: Can you draw a diagram to show what is happening. It isn't clear from your description what the geometry you're using is.

Comment: I have added the image. @JohnRennie

Comment: I think there will not be an angular momentum. But I will wait for a quantitative answer

Answer (score 1):

You assume that the angular momentum of the right hand rod will be zero after the rods have separated, but this is not so. Consider this diagram showing the rods before and after:

[image: Rods]

Angular momentum is always measured about some reference point. Any reference point can be used, but for convenience I've chosen the centre of mass of the two rods and I've marked this with the red dot.

Once the rods have separated we expect that the right rod will move right and won't be rotating wile the left rod will move left and will be rotating anti-clockwise. The point is that angular momentum is the velocity times the normal distance to the reference point. That means the right rod does have a non-zero angular momentum, and it's angular momentum will be equal and opposite to the total angular momentum of the left rod.

Comment: This answer is really helpful. I have a doubt, how do we measure the linear momentum. Do we use a reference point like you explained here.

Comment: @SanthiKabir: we don't use a reference point for measuring linear momentum, but we do use a reference frame. For example I'm stationary while I'm sat typing this so my momentum is zero. But hang on, at my latitude the rotation of the Earth means the surface is moving at about 290 m/sec so shouldn't my momentum be 290 times my mass? But then the Earth orbits the Sun at about 30,000 m/sec so shouldn't me momentum be 30,000 times my mass? And so on. To define the linear momentum we need to specify our frame. However, no matter what frame we use total momentum is always conserved.